# Batch Script Help Moving Folders into a Subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

Hey I have a custom batch script that I have cobbled together. The script sets up and cleans/organizes a job folder that I am about to start working in. It almost works how I need it to moving all files in the directory into a subfolder "Plans & Reports". I would like it to also **move all the folders into that directory as well**, though the move command doesn't seem to work for that as they and their contents remain unaffected when I try to include them.

Here is the current working code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
ECHO =      Welcome to the New Project Setup Wizard      =
ECHO =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
ECHO.
set /p npn="Enter Project Name: "

chcp 65001
md "Plans & Reports"
move "%CD%"\*.* "%CD%"\"Plans & Reports"
copy "%~dp0"\"New Project Template\0) Project - Ox Calc.xlsm"
copy "%~dp0"\"New Project Template\1) Project - Master.esw"
copy "%~dp0"\"New Project Template\θ) Project - Volume Report.pdf"
ren "0) Project - Ox Calc.xlsm" "0) %npn% - Ox Calc.xlsm"
ren "1) Project - Master.esw" "1) %npn% - Master.esw"
ren "θ) Project - Volume Report.pdf" "θ) %npn% - Volume Report.pdf"
chcp 437
```

[Image before the batch file is run via context menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTorA.png)

[Image after the batch file has run indicating the the additional changes I would like to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAPcT.png)

I am relatively certain I need to replace the move command with something that will move or copy/delete all the files **and Folders** into the "Plans & Reports" folder (excluding itself obviously).

```
move "%CD%"\*.* "%CD%"\"Plans & Reports"
```

I have tried to run xcopy and robocopy with no success. For example I tried this but don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
robocopy "%CD%\*.*" "%CD%\Plans & Reports" /move /xd "%CD%\Plans & Reports"
```

Copying and deleting is fine if that's a good solution but it needs to target the working directory as the source and the "Plans & Reports" subdirectory as the destination.

Thank you all in advance for any help you might provide.
Edits: Updated the scope of my intent for clarity.

Comment: For the line you've provided, and considering the `MOVE` works with files, I'd use `MOVE /Y * "Plans & Reports"`

Comment: @Compo I don't intend to move the folder into itself see image #2 linked above for clarity. If it needs an exclusion that would make sense but the code currently doesn't effect folders at all just files. I would like to have it move the folders though as well which is what I am struggling to figure out.

Comment: Move only affects files, not directories, for those, use robocopy.exe instead. BTW, in your supplied code, you really should use `Move "%CD%\*.*" "%CD%\Plans & Reports"` or `Move .\*.* "%CD%\Plans & Reports"` instead of `move "%CD%"\*.* "%CD%"\"Plans & Reports"`; `Copy "%~dp0New Project Template\0) Project - Ox Calc.xlsm"` instead of `copy "%~dp0"\"New Project Template\1) Project - Master.esw"`, and `Copy "%~dp0New Project Template\0) Project - Ox Calc.xlsm"`, instead of `copy "%~dp0"\"New Project Template\1) Project - Master.esw"`.

Comment: So given that you need `xcopy.exe` or `Robocopy.exe`, _(which superceded it over twelve years ago)_, and have apparently tried those without success, then that is what you should have posted. We cannot help you to fix one of at least two different commands you've failed with, but have not submitted. The usage information for each is clearly documented using `xcopy /?` and `robocopy /?`.

Comment: @Compo I appreciate your attempt to help but this doesn't seemed to have changed anything functionally and indeed seems to only nit pick at placement of the quotation marks. I don't know if there is a significance to the difference you outlined but both instances work as intended regardless and don't address the issue.

I am asking for help with using either robocopy or xcopy or move. I don't really know what I am doing with these commands as I'm unsure how to translate them effectively with batch script. How would you write a command to accomplish the goal?

Comment: Actually not nit pick, because file paths cannot include double-quotes, so including them means that the parser has to handle and then ignore therm. Also `%~dp0` already includes a trailing backward slash, so adding another one is also something which has to be handled and then ignored too. You wouldn't generally use `"C:\Users\Bryce"\\"Desktop"`, rather than `"C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop"`, would you?

Comment: Yes I already made the changes you suggested but it doesnt seem to change the function or accomplish the goal. would this work? `robocopy "%CD%\*.*" "%CD%\Plans & Reports" /move /xd "%CD%\Plans & Reports"`

Comment: No, it does not follow the basic syntax listed in the command help and usage information, I've already told you about how to access. The syntax is something along the lines of `ROBOCOPY source destination [files] [options]`, and you've used `ROBOCOPY source\[files] destination [options]`. Also you do not ever need to use `%CD%` in any of these cases, the current directory is always the default if no path is provided. You already understood that when you used `md "Plans & Reports"` instead of `md "%CD%"\"Plans & Reports"`, or more correctly `MD "%CD%\Plans & Reports"`.

Comment: the powershell tag seems wrong here. if that is NOT the case, please add a note about why ... otherwise, please remove it.  [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey removed the tag sorry for that I thought batch script called powershell or command line so thought it might be relevant I really have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: BTW @Bryce, instead of copying a file with the COPY command, and then later renaming it with the REN command, why don't you include a destination in your COPY command complete with the new filename as the destination. That way you can do it in a single pass/command instead of two.

Comment: @Compo Yeah that might be good if I had any idea how to do that. When I say I cobbled this batch script together I really mean that. I don't have any background with codding at all and while I have referenced many sites that explain syntax I am usually stuck with trial and error for a few hours till I can get something to work. This is my first post here, and I feel more attacked for my lack of knowledge and understanding than like I am being welcomed or helped. Thanks for the recommendation maybe I'll figure that out after I'm done finding out how to fix the syntax on robocopy.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You can do that for almost any cmd.exe command or built-in Windows CLI utility.

Comment: @Bryce - thank you! i appreciate it ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution that works for me. I was trying this which didn't work...

```
robocopy "%CD%\*.*" "%CD%\Plans & Reports" /move /xd "%CD%\Plans & Reports"
```

and changed it to this, which did!

```
robocopy .\ "Plans & Reports" *.* /e /move /XD "Plans & Reports"
```

So the `%CD%` are pointless as far as I can tell with robocopy. Better to use `.\` as the dot means "this directory". Thus <source> is `.\` and the <destination> is `"Plans & Reports"` which is in <source> already so it doesn't need a full path I guess?

The `*.*` is the file matcher it means any file or folder, as far as I can tell I don't know the windows wildcards or any of what I'm doing really. It also needs to be on it's own and as the third argument.

Everything else tells it what and how to copy or not. It apparently doesn't like some of the stuff I did and responds inline with errors but it will actually do what I'm wanting so I don't really care to much.

Have to give credit to a friend of mine off site who helped me work this out and understand it to a rudimentary degree. Much more help than I found on this site.

Comment: I'm glad you got there in the end. As a side note, you do not and should not have a trailing backward slash on your source or destination directory paths/names. Also if you check back on the usage information you should see 'File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*")'. That means that you do not need to specify that either. For example `%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe . "Plans & Reports" /E /Move /XD "Plans & Reports" 1>NUL`.